# How to use -tap in gdal_rasterize

Tags: gdal, gdal-rasterize

I have read the gdal documentation for [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html). As well as reading the original forum that established -tap (target aligned pixels). I understand -tap  is used to make a standard grid (maybe like ArcGIS snap raster) but I do not understand the usage.

**When I use gdal_rasterize and I enter -tap what is -tap actually doing to the ouput raster?**

I do not seem to be able to point -tap to another raster to use this grid and I do not seem to be able to enter origin coordinates. Gdal_rasterize appears to want me to enter only -tap with no following argument. My assumption is it aligns with 0,0 but this is a guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-tap just aligns the grid to the resolution. So, if the resolution is 2m, the cells are aligned to round multiples of 2.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like a snap raster setting in gdal_rasterize.

Comment: I don't think -tap would work because, for example, you couldn't snap the grid to a fraction if the resolution was an integer. You can use the -te flag to explicitly set the extent, along with -tr to set the resolution. You can get the snap extent from the snap raster using gdalinfo. A pain, I know. In GRASS, you can just set the region by the snap raster, but GDAL isn't meant to be a full GIS.